# "Define is not defined" in Jest when testing es6 module with RequireJS dependency

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a Jest test suite that fails to run because the component it's trying to test depends on a RequireJS module. Here's the error I'm seeing:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/components/MyComponent.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: define is not defined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/private-npm-module/utils.js:1:90)
```

The component has the following import:

```
import utils from 'private-npm-module';
```

And the `private-npm-module` is set up like so:

```
define('utils', [], function() {
  return {};
});
```

When `MyComponent` is transpiled with babel and run in the browser, the dependency operates correctly. This issue only affects the unit test. How can I get my test suite to run on a component with a RequireJS dependency?

I'm using `babel-jest` as my `scriptPreprocessor` in package.json's jest config. I'm using jest v0.15.1.

Comment: There is (rejected) feature request for support of AMD JavaScript modules in Jest, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/17

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, RequireJS is not supported by Jest. In my particular case, it was easiest and most appropriate to mock my dependency at the top of `MyComponent.test.js`:

```
jest.mock('private-npm-module', () => {
  // mock implementation
})

import MyComponent from '../../components/MyComponent';
```

This way, when `MyComponent` is loaded, its dependency is already mocked, so it won't try to load the RequireJS module.

If you really do need to load your RequireJS module for your test, it may be possible to use [jest's `transform` configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-object-string-string) to wrap your implementation in a RequireJS to ES6 converter.