# Jest - ReferenceError: define is not defined for a simple test file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to use jest to test my project but upon running `npm run test`, I get `ReferenceError: define is not defined` even though my test file is extremely simple.

```
test("Adding 1 + 1 equals 2", () => {
  expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
});
```

This leads to me thinking that my setup configuration is wrong but I dont think I've done anything in my configurations that could have led to this (I think).

I'm confused as to why it's telling me `define` isn't defined when I'm not directly using `define` in my test case. I would appreciate any pointers!

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my `package.json`

```
"jest": {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testURL": "http://localhost",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.css$": "./config/jest/cssTransform.js",
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "./config/jest/fileTransform.js"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "web.js",
    "js",
    "json",
    "web.jsx",
    "jsx",
    "node",
    "mjs"
  ]
}
```

EDIT 2: I've discovered that even if I had nothing in my test file, I get the same `ReferenceError: define is not defined` error

Comment: Can you share your jest configuration?

Comment: @Volodymyr I've updated my original post with my jest config. Thanks

Comment: Are you using RequireJS? As far as I know RequireJS is not supported by Jest.

Comment: @LazerBass Hi! Yes I'm using RequireJS and is there no way around it? I'm sure that something as popular as jest must have some kind of solution? :-(

Comment: @Tim Yeah, at least it seems that there are no plans to support it https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/17. And I don't know of any workaround.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919028/define-is-not-defined-in-jest-when-testing-es6-module-with-requirejs-dependenc

Comment: @rc_dz Thanks! I've discovered that actually even if I leave my test file blank, i still get the same error. Not sure what the source of this could be actually if I'm not doing anything in the test file

Comment: @LazerBass ah thanks for making me aware of it. I've updated my post with another discovery I made that even if my test file is empty, I still get the same error. This makes me unsure of if this is actually a requirejs problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem was in my `.babelrc` . Changed it to:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": []
    },
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    }
  },
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": false,
  "ignore": [
    "build",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and the error went away :-)

Comment: Hi @Tim, what is the specific changes in your .babelrc that fix the issue?

Comment: @DarrylR.Norbert If I recall correctly it was an issue with my env

Answer (score 0):

That's because we have the `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd` so that while process test tasks the code will be transformed to `define()` AMD format, that's where the error's `define` from. Specify the babel config for jest test can solve this.

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = api => {
  const commonConfig = {/* preset configs or something */};
  if( !api.env("test") ){
    commonConfigs.plugins.push("@babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd");
  }

  return commonConfig;
}
```

[Jest API Reference / Making your Babel config jest-aware](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel)

---

About the transformed code
this command will show you cache directory of test code,

```sh
npx jest --showConfig | grep cacheDirectory
# /private/var/folders/dc/7gkfb6ns0c79ll9gv2y3m6_w0010gn/T/jest_dx
```

open that folder you may see some files in `jest_dx/jest-transform-cache-{HASH}/{QueueNumber}`, the file is just there.